# onCreate() is not called even when Database version is increased

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm trying to add a new table using `onUpgrade()`. I have given the query to create a table in it which is executed if the oldVersion is lesser than the newVersion. I have increased the database version but I'm getting `NullPointerException` in the `db.execSQL()` in `onUpgrade()` for `db`.

I check in debug mode and see that in `onUpgrade()` the newVersion(here i2 in my code) is still 7(see code) though I changed to 8.

Why am I getting `NullPointerException` for `db` in `onUpgrade()`. I have defined value for the `SQLiteDatabase db` in the `onCreate()` as `this.db = db`(the value I get from the method `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db,..)`) and I have called `onUpgrade` in the constructor of class extending `SQLiteOpenHelper` and passed the oldVersion and newVersion values to it. Sorry if I confused you by trying to explain too much. I'm new to android and don't know if this is even the right way to add a new table to existing database.

Here's the code:

**DatabaseHelper.class**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 9;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database";
SQLiteDatabase db;
ArrayList<String> arrayList;
Context cont;

DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.cont = context;
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    this.onUpgrade(db, 7, 8);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table tableName(name text,email text primary key,password varchar,phno int)");
    db.execSQL("create table bookingDetails(email text, date text, time text,vehicle text,fromLocation text,destination text)");
    db.execSQL("create table emptyTable (name text)");
    db.execSQL("insert into emptyTable values(ad)");
    this.db = db;
}

public boolean save(String name, String email, String password, String phno) {
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("name", name);
    values.put("email", email);
    values.put("password", password);
    values.put("phno", phno);
    long rows;
    rows = db.insert("tableName", null, values);
    if (rows <= 0) {
        Toast.makeText(cont, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;

    }
    return true;
}

public String getUserName(String email) {
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select name from tableName where email = '" + email + "'", null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c.getString(0);

}

public void saveBookingDetails(String email, String date, String time, String vehicleType, String fromLocation, String destination) {
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("email", email);
    values.put("date", date);
    values.put("time", time);
    values.put("vehicle", vehicleType);
    values.put("fromLocation", fromLocation);
    values.put("destination", destination);
    long rows;
    rows = db.insert("bookingDetails", null, values);
    if (rows <= 0) {
        Toast.makeText(cont, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else
        Toast.makeText(cont, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


public void delete() {
    db.execSQL("delete from bookingDetails");
}

public ArrayList displayUserDetails(String email) {
    int i = 0;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select name,email,phno from tableName where email = '" + email + "'", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
        arrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
        arrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("email")));
        arrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("phno")));
        i++;
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    return arrayList;
}

public boolean getLogin(String email, String pass) {
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select password from tableName where email = '" + email + "'", null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst() && cursor.getCount() > 0 && cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.getString(0).equals((pass))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}

public long getTaskCount() {
    return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(getReadableDatabase(), "tableName");
}

public ArrayList getBookingHistory(String email) {
    ArrayList bookingHistoryList = new ArrayList();
    String e = email;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from bookingDetails where email = '" + email + "'", null);
    int cou = c.getCount();
    c.moveToFirst();
    do {
        bookingHistoryList.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date")));
        bookingHistoryList.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("time")));
        bookingHistoryList.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("fromLocation")));
        bookingHistoryList.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("destination")));
        bookingHistoryList.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("vehicle")));
    }
    while (c.moveToNext());
    return bookingHistoryList;
}

public ArrayList getTextViewText() {
    ArrayList txtViewList = new ArrayList();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from tableName", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
        txtViewList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
        txtViewList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("email")));
        txtViewList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("phno")));
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    return txtViewList;
}

public void saveOnEdit(String email, String name, String phno, String password) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();


    if (name.length() == 0) {
        if (phno.length() == 0) {
            values.put("password", password);
            db.update("tableName", values, "email = '" + email + "'", null);
        } else if (password.length() == 0) {
            values.put("phno", phno);
            db.update("tableName", values, "email = '" + email + "'", null);
        } else {
            values.put("phno", phno);
            values.put("password", password);
        }
    } else if (password.length() == 0 && phno.length() == 0) {
        values.put("name", name);
        db.update("tableName", values, "email = '" + email + "'", null);
    } else if (password.length() == 0) {
        values.put("name", name);
        values.put("phno", phno);
        db.update("tableName", values, "email = '" + email + "'", null);
    } else if (phno.length() == 0) {
        values.put("name", name);
        values.put("password", password);
        db.update("tableName", values, "email = '" + email + "'", null);
    } else {
        values.put("name", name);
        values.put("password", password);
        values.put("phno", phno);
        db.update("tableName", values, "email = '" + email + "'", null);
    }
}

public String empty() {
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select name from emptyTable", null);
    return c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i2) {
    if (i < i2) {
        db.execSQL("create table emptyTable(name text)");
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("name", "ad");
        db.insert("emptyTable", null, values);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onConfigure(db);
}

@Override
public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    super.onDowngrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
}

@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onOpen(db);
}
}
```

Comment: Ok..But why am I getting `NullPointerException`? in the `db` for `onUpgrade()` I have defined the value for `db` in the constructor using `this.getWritableDatabase()`

Comment: or simply u can drop table in onUpgrade() and call onCreate(sqLiteDatabase)  from onUpgrade. Refer Link: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onUpgrade` you're using the wrong reference:

```
    db.execSQL("create table emptyTable(name text)");
```

instead of

```
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table emptyTable(name text)");
```

---

Your constructor will invoke the upgrade and create **before** you get the database reference, thus it's still null when upgrading.

Comment: You're right. But I'm getting "table already exists" error. I don't know in which one of my trials I managed to create the table but probably got some other error. Anyway, is this the right way to add a new table? Calling `onUpgrade()` in this constructor doesn't seem right. Can you please edit your answer and also say how to do it the right way?

Comment: @Abhi you multiple lengthy questions sorry I can't answer them all in one thread. However, the reason why you get "table already exists" is because the table was already created in `onCreate`. Read the documentation for `onCreate`, `onUpgrade` and `getWritableDatabase` it'll make things a lot clearer.

Answer (score 0):

When database version increase You have to call `onCreate` by calling it in `onUpgrade` like this :

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    onCreate(db);
}
```